# Tkinter checkbox executing command only once

Tags: python, tkinter

```
x = tk.IntVar()
def test():
   print(x.get())
checkBox = tk.Checkbutton(text="test",command=test(),variable=x)
checkBox.grid(row=12,column=2)

b=tk.Button(text="test",command=test)
b.grid(row=12,column=0
```

this is some code I put in my program for testing, when I check the checkbox the value does change (I can confirm it with the button I made to test) but the command does not get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **()** in command

```py
command= test
```

This works fine:

```py
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
x = tk.IntVar()


def test():
    print(x.get())


checkBox = tk.Checkbutton(text="test", command=test, variable=x)
checkBox.grid(row=12, column=2)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's better to close these questions as [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/11106801) instead of answering them.

Comment: ok; indeed :) @TheLizzard